# Any way to add a border to a specific list item if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I'm making a JavaScript clock with the days of the week underneath and I'm hoping to put a little border around the current day. I've got the clock working perfectly, but I'm struggling with getting the border to appear around the current day using JavaScript. The layout on the page is as follows:

```
                             00 : 00 : 00
                    Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat Sun
```

Today is Monday so I want a border around "Mon" - and so on, for the corresponding day. I'm currently in the process of using .getDay() and using an IF statement to determine whether the .getDay() value matches up with an array I've created, and if it does, using document.getElementById to select the appropriate list item and add a border to it using "*element*.style.border = xxx, xxx, xxx;"

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
function showDay(){ 
    var day = new Date();
    var weekday = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    dayNum = weekday[day.getDay()];
    if(dayNum == 0){
        document.getElementById('0').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 1){
        document.getElementById('1').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 2){
        document.getElementById('2').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 3){
        document.getElementById('3').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 4){
        document.getElementById('4').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 5){
        document.getElementById('5').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
      if(dayNum == 6){
        document.getElementById('6').style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
    }
}
showDay();
```

Comment: And is there any problem with the given code? What happens if you run it? What is missing?

Comment: You can replace that entire, long-winded multi-if block with simply `document.getElementById(dayNum).style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;`

Comment: Nothing happens when I run it; the page stays exactly as it would be if there was no JavaScript code there at all. I would expect the border to appear around "Mon" but it's the same as before.

Comment: `border = 2px solid #18CAE6;` <-- syntax error, I am sure the error is in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it was not working for you is that you forgot to include parentheses `" "` around your border values (e.g. `"2px solid #18CAE6";`).

I added some example divs and a button to test applying the border dynamically.

**Note:** `.getDay()` returns the day of the week for the given date object as 0-6, where 0 represents Sunday and 6 represents Saturday.

---

Test below:

```js
function showDay(){ 
    let day = new Date();

    // you don't need the two lines below unless you are thinking of changing 
    // the ids of the elements to string representations
    // e.g. you can just do let dayNum = day.getDay();
    let weekday = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    let dayNum = weekday[day.getDay()];

    if(dayNum == 0){
        document.getElementById('0').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 1){
        document.getElementById('1').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 2){
        document.getElementById('2').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 3){
        document.getElementById('3').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 4){
        document.getElementById('4').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 5){
        document.getElementById('5').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
      if(dayNum == 6){
        document.getElementById('6').style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="0">Sun</div>
<div id="1">Mon</div>
<div id="2">Tues</div>
<div id="3">Wed</div>
<div id="4">Thur</div>
<div id="5">Fri</div>
<div id="6">Sat</div>


<input type="button" value="Apply border" onclick="showDay()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really see whats wrong.

Although dayNum is not made.

Also why would you make that array there is no point really because

```
day.getDay()
```

already gives an integer where monday would be 1.

You could maby use something like this:

```
var day = new Date();
var dayNum = day.getDay();
document.getElementById(dayNum).style.border = 2px solid #18CAE6;
```

Hope this helpes!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons it's not running. First, you need to wrap those style strings in quotes, like:

```
document.getElementById('0').style.border = '2px solid #18CAE6';
```

Second, HTML ids can't start with (or be just) a number. Try changing your `"div id='1'` to something like `"div id='day-1'"`. Something that starts with a letter.

You can also trim this down a lot by looking for repeated patterns. In every line, you're saying, "if x is the day, put the border on element x". So instead of all these individual cases, just do this, assuming you've changed your ids to `day-1`, `day-2`, etc:

```
function showDay(){ 
    var day = new Date();
    var weekday = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    var dayNum = weekday[day.getDay()];

    document.getElementById('day-' + dayNum).style.border = "2px solid #18CAE6";
}
```

Does that all make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense and it worked like a charm!